# More efficient way of writing this javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am creating a contact form for my website and and using javascript to the first layer of validation before submitting it which is then checked again via php but i am relatively new to javascript, here is my script...

```
$("#send").click(function() {
    var fullname = $("input#fullname").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var subject = $("input#subject").val();
    var message = $("textarea#message").val();
    if (fullname == ""){
        $("input#fullname").css("background","#d02624");
        $("input#fullname").css("color","#121212");
    }else{
        $("input#fullname").css("background","#121212");
        $("input#fullname").css("color","#5c5c5c");
    }
    if (email == ""){
        $("input#email").css("background","#d02624");
        $("input#email").css("color","#121212");
    }else{
        $("input#email").css("background","#121212");
        $("input#email").css("color","#5c5c5c");
    }
    if (subject == ""){
        $("input#subject").css("background","#d02624");
        $("input#subject").css("color","#121212");
    }else{
        $("input#subject").css("background","#121212");
        $("input#subject").css("color","#5c5c5c");
    }
    if (message == ""){
        $("textarea#message").css("background","#d02624");
        $("textarea#message").css("color","#121212");
    }else{
        $("textarea#message").css("background","#121212");
        $("textarea#message").css("color","#5c5c5c");
    }
    if (name && email && subject && message != ""){
        alert("YAY");
    }
});
```

How can i write this more efficiently and make the alert show if all the fields are filled out, thanks.

Comment: You know that this: `if (name && email && subject && message != "")` is not comparing all of those variables against the empty string, only `message`? You probably meant `if (name != "" && email != "" && subject != "" && message != "")` Your way will still work because `if (someVar)` tests to see if `someVar` can be coerced to a "truthy" value, and non-empty strings are "truthy", but if you're going to rely on that then why test `message != ""` at the end. (Or your way _would_ work if you changed `name` to `fullname` to match the variable declaration.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#send").click(function() {
    var failed = false;

    $('input#fullname, input#email, input#subject, textarea#message').each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
        if (item.val()) {
            item.css("background","#121212").css("color","#5c5c5c");
        } else {
            item.css("background","#d02624").css("color","#121212");
            failed = true;
        }
    });

    if (failed){
        alert("YAY");
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, it seems `failed` is set if _any_ of the items is set, whereas in the original code _every_ item must be set.
Swapping `true` and `false` should do it, i believe (passed).

Comment: failed is TRUE when at least one element is empty. So only if(failed) should be fixed to if (!failed). I thought YAY is ERROR ;-)

Comment: Ok, the other guy seems to have given up, and unlike the other solutions this one actually works how i intended it to since it was fixed, thanks for the help and you are the new champion of this page!

Comment: Like I wrote in comment on Lyndon post, use classes, do not use static css rules like this. CSS rules belong in css files ;-)

Comment: +1 for showing him multiple selectors and chaining. That functionality drastically clarifies your code.

Answer (score 4):

glavic and matt's answers were exactly what I was going to suggest, except I would take it a step further by separating the logic from the presentation.

Have classes defined in your css for when a field contains an invalid entry, and add or remove that class using `$.addClass()` or `$.removeClass()`

Comment: ^ this - I am constantly doing this on SO when I know better that you really should have a predefined class for indicating an error.

Comment: True. I never use static css options in javascript. All css is in *.css files ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, I would recommend setting a class on each field that requires a non-blank value (class="required").

Then you do something like this:

```
var foundEmpty = false;
$(".required").each(function()
{
   if($(this).val())
   {
       foundEmpty=true;
       $(this).style("background-color", "red");
   }
});
if(foundEmpty)
{
  alert("One or more fields require a value.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving them a common class, define classes to apply the styles, and do this:

***JS***

```
$("#send").click(function() {
    $('.validate').attr("class", function() {
        return $(this).val() === "" ? "validate invalid" : "validate valid";
    });
    if( $('.invalid').length === 0 ) {
        alert('YAY');
    }
});
```

***CSS***

```
.valid {
    background:#121212;
    color:#5c5c5c
}

.invalid {
    background:#d02624;
    color:#121212;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<button id="send">SEND</button><br>
<input class="validate"><br>
<input class="validate"><br>
<input class="validate"><br>
<input class="validate">
```

---

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxGwP/)**

---

A little bit more efficient approach:

```
var validate = $('.validate');

$("#send").click(function() {
    validate.attr("class", function() {
        return $(this).val() === "" ? "validate invalid" : "validate valid";
    });
    if( validate.filter('.invalid').length === 0 ) {
        alert('YAY');
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution, but how would this check if all the fields are NOT empty and execute the next part of the script e.g if (complete){alert("YAY");}

Comment: @nblackburn: Yep, I left that off. Updated.

Comment: Awesome, is there any chance of doing this without adding another class to the form fields because i already them defined.

Comment: @nblackburn: Which class do you mean? You can use your existing class instead of the `"validate"` class that I used. And it's harmless to add additional classes like `"valid"` and `"invalid"`. So just make it `"your_current_class invalid"` and  `"your_current_class valid"`.

Comment: ah, i ment a way of using your code without adding the "validate" class to fields that i want to validate, i know i can add multiple classes but its starting to look messy, so i was trying to cut down on using too many.

Comment: The examples don't seem to be working correctly, it only highlights the textarea not the other input fields and when i click on the field to correct it, it changes back temporary until i click somewhere else instead of staying the "invalid" colour until i click send again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to iterate over each object and get their values. Depending on your form, this code will change, but it's to give you an example. I'm probably missing a couple of brackets here and there but the concept is there.

```
var objectName=$(this).attr('id');    
$('#formId').children().each(
        function(){

            if ($(this).value == ""){
                 $(this).css("background","#d02624");
                 $(this).css("color","#121212");
                 $error[objectName]='true';

            }else{
                 $(this).css("background","#121212");
                 $(this).css("color","#5c5c5c");
                 $error[objectName]='false';
            }




        }
    );
           $.each(error, function(key, value){


                if (value=='false'){
                  alert (key + 'is empty');
                }
           });
```

Answer (score -1):

I would probably divide part of this up into my css file. If any of the fields are empty add a class like "empty" to the object, if not, remove it. Then in your css file you can add some descriptors like:

```
input#fullname,
input#email {
   ...
}

input#fullname.empty,
input#email.empty {
    ...
}
```

You can use jQuery addClass() and removeClass().

You can then add a loop as follows:

```
var inputs = new Array();
inputs[0] = "input#fullname";
inputs[1] = "input#email";
inputs[2] = "input#subject";
inputs[3] = "textarea#message";
var complete = true;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var value = $(inputs[0]).val();
    if (value.length > 0) {
        $(inputs[i]).removeClass("empty");
    } else {
        complete = false;
        $(inputs[i]).addClass("empty");
    }
}
if (complete) {
}
```

EDIT:

There you go, fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks dude, this means alot to me, i didn't think of adding all the field names into an array, good idea!

Comment: Merging this solution with Matt's would make this code pretty rock solid. If you ever needed to add a control to the form all you would need to do is add it to the html and css.

Comment: How did this answer get accepted? In that little bit of code, you've managed to squeeze in `SyntaxError`, `ReferenceError` and `TypeError`.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, we are not here to error check code for users looking for answers, we're here to get them on the right path. I expected there to be errors but I expect the OP can understand that ellipses are not valid instructions in javascript and that when I make small typos, they will easily be identified and corrected.

Comment: *"we are not here to error check code for users looking for answers"* Sure we are. And I wasn't talking about the ellipses at all. All the errors take place above the `if(complete)` statement.